# Zabbix monitoring Glassfish JVM

Tags: glassfish, monitoring, zabbix

I installed zabbix server all went okay, i also installed the zabbix agent in Glassfish VM, Now i'm trying to monitor my JVM (In Glassfish VM), i did the following :

In Glassfish jvm options i added :

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9000
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=8787
```

So can i monitor my JVM from 8787 or 9000 port with zabbix or do i need to install zabbix-java-getway in my Glassfish VM and monitor my JVM from the default port 10052 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to monitor a JVM process over JMX, you need to install zabbix-java-gateway which is then access either by the Zabbix server or by a proxy.

Zabbix server or proxy would connect to java gateway that listens on port 10052 and the gateway would connect to the JVM via JMX port 9000.

The proxy needs to know the port of the gateway (10052) and it also knows the JMX port, which it passes to the gateway. So no configuration is on the gateway, only if you want to define a different port than 10052.